# The difference of "addEventListener" and "onxx" when event processing

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

I know `addEventListener` can add a lot of handlers, "onxx" just have one handler, and `addEventListener` can remove the handler, but one thing I can't understand is: why when I use onxx, my console get log correctly, but when I use `addEventListener` I can't get `mousemove` event proper.

When I use `addEventListener`, I press my mouse down then I move the mouse. It doesn't trigger the `mousemove` event continually, but when I use "onxx" It works!

```
<html> 
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "div">
            <div id = "div1">
                <img id="omna" src="http://online1.map.bdimg.com/tile/?qt=tile&x=0&y=0&z=4&styles=pl&udt=20141102" width="256px" height="256px" unselectable="on" style="position:absolute top:0px left:0px"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img id="omna" src="http://online1.map.bdimg.com/tile/?qt=tile&x=0&y=0&z=4&styles=pl&udt=20141102" width="256px" height="256px" unselectable="on" style="position:absolute top:0px left:256px"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            var eventutil = {
                addHandler : function(element, type, handler){
                    if(element){
                        if(element.addEventListener){
                            element.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
                        }else if(element.attachEvent){
                            element.attachEvent("on"+type, handler);
                        }else {
                            element["on"+type] = handler;
                        }
                    }
                },

                removeHandler : function(element, type, handler){
                    if(element){
                        if(element.removeEventListener ){
                            element.removeEventListener(type, handler, false);
                        }else if(element.detachEvent ){
                            element.detachEvent("on"+type, handler);
                        }else{
                            element["on"+type] = null;
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            function myonmousedown (){
                console.log("mousedown");
                return false;
            };
            
            function myonmousemove (){
                console.log("mousemove");

            }
            window.onload = function(){
                var div = document.getElementById("div");
                eventutil.addHandler(div, "mousedown", myonmousedown);
                eventutil.addHandler(div, "mousemove", myonmousemove);
            }

        </script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: They both seem to work fine for me. BTW, HTML documents must have a non–empty title element, but that has nothing to do with your issue.

Comment: @RobG When I use addEventListener, I press my mouse down then I move the mouse. It doesn't trigger the "mousemove" event continuely.but when I use "onxx" It works!

Comment: It seems that when *addEventListener* is used, a mousedown followed by move is interpreted as a drag, not a mousemove (there may be a few moves dispatched initially). However, when direct property assignment is used, it blocks the drag so move events are dispatched. Getting rid of `return false` from *onmymousedown* fixes that.

Comment: @RobG When I change "eventutil.addHandler(div, "mousedown", myonmousedown);" to "eventutil.addHandler(div, "startdrag", myonmousedown);" and change "eventutil.addHandler(document.body, "mousemove", myonmousemove);" to "eventutil.addHandler(document.body, "drag", myonmousemove);" It works! And I find this : http://help.dottoro.com/ljmojcxu.php.